# SQL data type - recommendation for 'unknown' number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I'm pulling in some external data into my MSSQL server.  Several columns of incoming data are marked as 'number' (it's a json file).  It's millions of rows in size and many of the columns appear to be `decimal (18,2)` like `23.33`.  But I can't be sure that it will always be like that, in fact a few have been `23.333` or longer numbers like `23.35555555` which will mess up my import.

So my question is given a column is going to have some kind of number imported into it, but I can't be sure really how big or how many decimal places it's going to have... do I have to resort to making my column a `varchar` or is there a very generic number kind of column I'm not thinking of?

Is there a max size decimal, sort of like using `VARCHAR(8000)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)` ?

**update**

This is the 'data type' of `number` that I'm pulling in:
https://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/number.html#

Looks like it can be pretty much any number, as per their writing:
"Numbers are arbitrary precision, arbitrary scale numbers."

Comment: You could use decimal(18,3) to allow for values with 3 significant digits.

Comment: Float perhaps, but you lose the precision in that, rounding can occur. It's an approximate-number data type. Not sure what this value represents for you, or how you are using it. If you can ask what's the maximum scale and precision you'd see, then I'd make the column that... like (32,6) or whatever...

Comment: A) You can make your decimal precision longer. b) Before inserting the data you can ROUND/FLOOR your values. But dont use a varchar.

Comment: Is there a max size decimal, sort of like using `VARCHAR(8000)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)` ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to consider storage. It will be really expensive if you store e.g. 2.2200000000 if you dont need to.

Comment: Precision and Scale max is 38 digits (to the right of the decimal). The scale must be <= to the precision. so Decimal (38,38)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The datatype I would use would depend on what the data in that column is going to be used for.   Do you know the answer to that, or can you find out?

Comment: You could always define it as something massive like 38,10, then after it's imported determine the actual max precision/scale through some queries, then add a 2nd column defined at this max precision/scale, and move the data over -- then drop the old huge column.

Comment: Normally, DECIMAL(18,2) will be enough, sometimes you go with more precision, but it wont go above (21,2) unless the company is dealing with thousands of trillions. In MS Dynamics, I saw they actually use real instead of decimal, not sure why, but I think they have a good reason for that.

Comment: JSON's numbers ought to be safe to parse as `float`, because that's what they are in JavaScript: double-precision floating point. Anything that's not safe to parse as that is probably going to be put into a string. Of course, you may still need another type in the database depending on how those numbers are going to be *used*, but the JSON can't tell you that.

Comment: I like that idea of using a `float` I had not thought of that.  The numbers coming in from a `json` file are simply called labeled `number`.  Actually, I'm going to update the question a bit.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've found more info about their datatype of 'number', I've updated my question.  Basically:  "Numbers are arbitrary precision, arbitrary scale numbers. "  I'm not sure if `float` will be able to handle that kind of mess.

Comment: It's one thing to write that numbers may be "arbitrary precision, arbitrary scale", but quite another to expect clients to handle this. For instance, no website that uses JavaScript to parse those requests is going to say "oh yeah, better use a bignum library for that"! Which is also why they wisely state that "since numbers can be either larger or more precise than what doubles allow, many formats, such as JSON, serialize them as strings." You'll be getting strings, then, and it's up to you to decide what to do next. T-SQL does not have an arbitrary precision number type, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your input.   Looks like I'll just stuff them in a staging table as `VARCHAR(8000)` or `MAX` and try to process it downstream :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I handle things like this is to import the raw data into a staging table in a `varchar(max)` column.

Then I use `TRY_PARSE()` or `TRY_CONVERT()` when moving it to the desired datatype in my final destination table.

The point here is that the shape of the incoming data shouldn't determine the datatype you use.   The datatype should be determined by the usage of the data once it's in your table.   And if the incoming data doesn't fit, there are ways of making it fit.

Comment: . . .  You should also point out the SQL Server Version which has those functions.

Comment: I like this idea.  My current testing is just to dump it into a `STAGE` table as `VARCHAR(8000)`, I wasn't aware of the `TRY_PARSE()` OR `TRY_CONVERT()` functions, thank you!

Comment: I've updated my question, I have more information that the 'number' data type are: "Numbers are arbitrary precision, arbitrary scale numbers. "

Answer (score 2):

What do those numbers represent? If they are just values to show you could just set float as datatype and you're good to go.
But if they are coordinates or currencies or anything you need for absolute precise calculations float might sometimes give rounding problems. Then you should set your desired minimal precision with decimal and simply truncate what's eventually over.
For instance if most of the numbers have two decimals, you could go with 3 or 4 decimal points to be sure, but over that it will be cut.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I've updated my question, I have more information that the 'number' data type are: "Numbers are arbitrary precision, arbitrary scale numbers. "